# Webpack: How to have runtime (not buildtime) feature flags with same module names?

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack, lazy-loading

I'm hoping to find a way to have alternate versions of the same file available from the same webpack run and same output url, with a different chunk/bundle being dynamically loaded after a service call determines which group a user falls into.

Background:

Putting alpha/beta changes into production in the same build and output url lets us develop and test features with external users, but sticking conditionals everywhere (and later removing them) that needs can change is error-prone and generates more complicated code.

My thought was to have alternate versions of the same files in specially named subdirs - e.g. foo/file.js and foo/flagged--special/file.js - and then when something does import blah from 'foo/file' it will automatically get the correct version for that user.

This avoids conditionals in the code itself, and making a feature available for all is just overwriting the base file with the alternate.  It also doesn't involve huge changes to our existing codebase and webpack config, nor does it involve a lot of funky and product-specific syntax to replace all our import statements.  (After I put the idea together, someone pointed me to Mendel, where Yahoo did much the same thing, albeit as their own framework that is not friendly with webpack, so I'm assuming the base idea isn't crazy)

Problems:

I see examples of feature-flagging a build to one version or the other, but not any examples of having both in one build.

I could write a custom loader or plugin to wrap each file load to do this (I think - not sure about how the output of webpack works in terms of runtime evaluation), but that would result in adding both versions to the bundle.

I'm thinking I can create a base output chunk that does little more than fetch the user's options, then dynamically load one of two alternate chunks that have the different versions...but I have no idea if that will work, or if I'm fighting a losing war vs the webpack internals.

- Can this work?
- Has someone already done this?
- Is there a better way?

Thanks in advance!